# How to change the Equaliser settings of each and every song in my iTunes library all at once?

Tags: macos, itunes, mac, music

I recently discovered that iTunes has support for Equaliser, but these option/setting is available if and only you click on the get album info button and set the Equaliser in the next window according to your needs, but this option is available if and only you click on a particular song, I mean you have to individually set the equaliser for each and every song in my iTunes library now it is not possible to change the equaliser setting of each and every song, I mean I have an iTunes library of 48 GB

So, I thought there might be a centralised option to change the Equaliser setting of each and every song all at once and guess what there is not such option in the preferences menu of iTunes!
Can anyone tell me how to change the Equaliser setting of each and every song at once!

Comment: Would it not be simpler to open the global EQ control from the iTunes Window menu & set it from there? What happens if you later changed your mind, or got different speakers etc?